# How to fix xamarin iOS linker from removing the code to prevent app crash?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, linker, xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin.Forms PCL project. I've enabled the Linker to link sdk assemblies only. The loads faster, works faster and smaller in size but in few areas it crashes. I'm not able to find out the bug because it works fine when the linker is disabled. I've included few lines in a file LinkerPleaseInclude as suggested by someone.

```
var x = new System.ComponentModel.ReferenceConverter(typeof(void));
```

After including this line, the app don't crash in few areas but the data don't show like dynamic data template of a listview. Do I need to include something else in the file LinkerPleaseInclude?
How can I prevent the linker from not removing the code while linker enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, I created the DynamicDataTemplate in my listview to dynamically show the multiple kind of items. I removed that and created a multiple template selector and now its working fine. 
I don't know how the linker will work with DynamicDataTemplate because I tried the Preserve attribute with that but it didn't work. But now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can hint the linker to not link-out types decorated by a `[Preserve]` attribute.

This attributes is not publicly exposed, but as it is voluntary looked for by name (instead of by type), you can define your own.

```cs
namespace Your.Namespace.Here
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public bool AllMembers;
        public bool Conditional;

        public PreserveAttribute(bool allMembers, bool conditional)
        {
            AllMembers = allMembers;
            Conditional = conditional;
        }

        public PreserveAttribute()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You can then decorate your types, or methods, that aren't explicitly referenced by code, like types accessed from Xaml only, or via reflection, with the `[Preserve]` attribute.

Comment: I need to add this to my iOS project and I'll need to add the [Preserve] attribute to everywhere in my PCL project?

Comment: no, only to the type that linker would remove otherwise

Comment: I've added the [Preserver] attribute to the classes but the app again crashes like it was crashing. I've tried to --linkskip=System.Runtime but nothing works. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've also tried to re create the page so that I can find a bug if any at that moment but its not working. App immediately crashes when that particular point comes

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix, can I also create a PreserveAttribute which takes Type as a constructor argument? I need to preserve typeof(System.Linq.Queryable) in one of my thrid party libraries.